# Showing Values in which there is a Substring that starts with a letter in range 'A' to 'X' followed by 2 letter of which second one is 'A' in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to find all the FIRST_NAMES in the table that looks like - There is a substring of 3 letter in the name of which first letter is in range 'A' to 'X' and 3rd one is 'A'. Moreover, the substring should be like '[A-X]_A' and the Name should be like '%[A-X]_A%'. But however ORACLE is showing **NO DATA FOUND** . Whenever I try with '[]' ORACLE can't find any data. Can anyone give me the solution?

For more information: I am using HR SCHEMA in LIVESQL.oracle.com for the purpose.

Comment: You are trying mostly with the `LIKE` operator for strings (where you find the `%` placeholder for "any text" and the underscore `_` for exactly one character), but you are mixing that with a character class (`[A-X]`) which exists only in regular expressions, not in standard string functions and conditions such as `LIKE`. Moreover, note that in one place you told us `A-X` but elsewhere you show `A-G`; please make up your mind.

Comment: Also: if you mean `FIRST_NAME` in the `EMPLOYEES` table in the `HR` schema, then there will not be any first names to match your pattern. Why? Because the names in that table are not ALL-CAPS, they are Initcap. The name `Alexander` will not match the pattern `EXA`, which would otherwise meet your requirements, because `exa` is not the same as `EXA`. Please check your homework assignment; if it is stated **exactly** as you shared it with us, then your teacher is just <word I will not type since it will be censored>.

Comment: @mathguy well, this was not my homework assignment directly. My teacher made some groups between us and told to make some difficult query and ask opponents for the solution. So I was thinking of this query if possible or not.

Answer (score 1):

You want a regular expression:

```
where regexp_like(col, '[A-X].A')
```